# JOIN multiple tables if the data is present

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm in a pickle.

I have created a race timing system that JOINs multiple tables. This is working correctly. There is a table for RFID readings (a tag ID and a time). A table for tag ID's matched with race numbers and a table for runners names with race numbers. This works fine...

```
SELECT s.firstName
        , s.lastName
        , s.event
        , h.time
        , h.action
        , h.tagId
    FROM $runnerTable s
    INNER JOIN $chipData hp
        on s.raceNumber = hp.bandID
    LEFT JOIN $readingTable h
        on hp.tagId = h.tagId WHERE event = 'Full' ORDER BY  h.action, h.time ASC
```

The problem I'm having is that I want to add a new table that has scan readings for a checkpoint along the race. So a new table called readingsCheckpoint exists. The issue is that some runners won't get scanned at the checkpoint for various reasons. I need to have a JOIN statement that adds in the new readingsCheckpoint data IF the value is there but not to return NULL from the statment if that value is not present. It will obviously be likely during the race a checkpoint scan exists before the finish time (present in the readingTable).

Current data examples...

Readings table with example data:

```
id, tagID, time, action
1,  12345, 1509, 1
```

Runners table with example data:

```
runnerId, raceNumber, firstName, lastName, event
1,      , 45        , Timothy  , Jones   , Full
```

chip data chipFiveTwice:

```
bandId, tagId
45    , 12345
```

And the new checkpoint table which is the same as the readings table:

```
id, tagID, checkTime, action
1,  12345, 1501 .   , 1
```

The current SQL above will produce a result like this:

```
firstName, lastName, event, raceNumber, time, action, tagId
Tim      , Jones   , Full , 45        , 1509, 1     , 12345
```

As you can see it joins up the RFID to a racer and presents their name and time.

How can I add the checkpoint scan to this SQL statement to produce this result?

```
firstName, lastName, event, raceNumber, time, checkTime, action, tagId
Tim      , Jones   , Full , 45        , 1509, 1501     , 1     , 12345
```

But for it to show a time if thee is one and/or a checkTime if there is one. Thanks in advance.

Comment: _"I need to have a JOIN statement that adds in the new readingsCheckpoint data IF the value is there but not to return NULL from the statment if that value is not present."_ What should it return when the value is not present? It has to return something.  Also, unrelated but, why are your table names variables?

Comment: Can you post some sample data and expected results? This is usually much more helpful than describing the issue with words when it comes to understanding the problem you are facing

Comment: example data and expected output go a long ways towards clarifying the specification, if there is a question. otherwise, thanks for posting a status report. we will note that we can add additional criteria in the `ON`  clause of a join, to restrict the rows that are joined, for example, to exclude rows that have NULL value for `data` column ... `LEFT JOIN readingsCheckpoint rc ON rc.tagid = hp.tagid AND rc.data IS NOT NULL`  The way an outer join works is when there isn't a matching row, a dummy row consisting of all NULL values is returned ...

Comment: Sorry for the poor explanation. I've now updated the original question to be a bit more explicit and include more detail.

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to solve the issue with some help from @spencer7593 and some extra logic on the WHERE part of the statement.

```
SELECT s.firstName
    , s.lastName
    , s.event
    , h.time
    , h.action
    , h.tagId
    , rc.checkTime
FROM runners s
INNER JOIN chipFiveTwice hp
    on s.raceNumber = hp.bandID
LEFT JOIN readings h on hp.tagId = h.tagId 
LEFT JOIN readingsCheckpoint rc ON rc.tagid = hp.tagid AND rc.checkTime IS NOT NULL
WHERE rc.checkTime IS NOT NULL OR h.time IS NOT NULL AND event = 'full'
```